# Different results returned by RcppArmadillo-defined functions with the same data

Tags: r, rcpp

Let `X` be a 3d-array with size `r*c*n` and `y` be a vector of length `n` with two levels. I want to compute the mean matrix of `X` grouped by `y`. Here I try to define the function using `arma::cube`, but every time calling the function, the results returned are different and very strange. Even for very small (`r`, `c`, `n`), the results always include `NaN`.

The content of **.cpp** file is as below:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List f(arma::cube X, CharacterVector y){
    unsigned int n     = X.n_slices;
    unsigned int rNums = X.n_rows;
    unsigned int cNums = X.n_cols;

    arma::mat mu1(rNums, cNums);
    arma::mat mu2(rNums, cNums);

    unsigned int n1 = 0;
    unsigned int n2 = 0;
    CharacterVector yLevels = sort_unique(y);
    for(unsigned int i=0; i < y.length(); i++){
        if(y[i] == yLevels[0]) {
            mu1 += X.slice(i);
            n1++;
        } else {
            mu2 += X.slice(i);
            n2++;
        }
    }
    mu1 /= n1;
    mu2 /= n2;

    return Rcpp::List::create(Named("mu1") = mu1,
                              Named("mu2") = mu2);
}
```

Then I call this **.cpp** file in R and call the function of both R and Cxx versions as followed:

```
> rm(list=ls())
> options(digits=2)
> library(Rcpp)
> sourceCpp("Cxx_File.cpp")
> 
> set.seed(2018)
> X <- array(rnorm(4*5*10), dim=c(4, 5, 10))
> y <- c(rep("1", 4), rep("2", 6))
> 
> f(X, y)
$mu1
      [,1]   [,2]   [,3]  [,4]   [,5]
[1,]  0.33  0.076  0.230  0.43 -0.801
[2,] -0.50 -0.145  0.162 -0.21  0.629
[3,] -0.13  0.516 -0.266 -0.37 -0.261
[4,]  0.73  0.226 -0.071 -0.36  0.035

$mu2
      [,1]   [,2]  [,3] [,4]   [,5]
[1,] 0.098  0.016  0.27 0.70  0.017
[2,] 0.434 -0.164  0.40 0.77  0.104
[3,] 0.060  0.226  0.05  NaN  0.091
[4,] 0.261  0.313 -0.47 0.18 -0.301
```

the result conains **NaN** which shouldnot have appeared. What is the reason?

Comment: This It's a little long.  Can you reduce it a little?

Comment: Sorry for the previously tedious codes. I have fix it to be a minimal exectable example. Plz check it again. 3gu very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That has to do with the fact that `arma::mat` does not initialize matrices with zeros. Add `mu1.fill(0)`, `mu2.fill(0)` and `sigma2.fill(0)` when you initialize these variables.

Comment: You can also force the matrices to be initialized with zeros [during construction](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Mat). Example: `arma::mat mu1(rNums, cNums, arma::fill::zeros);`

Comment: But I tried the code below, which showed that arma::mat initialize a matrix with zero entries. **arma::mat g(unsigned int r, unsigned int c){
  arma::mat mat(r, c);
  return mat + 1.0;
}**

Comment: I tried initialize zeros for the arma::mat and the results were no probelms. Thank your advice. But when I just returned the initialized arma::mat, it shown almost zeros matrix. WHY?

Comment: @zengchao - You just got lucky in that case. The memory at that specific location was full of zeros already. From the [documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Mat): _When specifying the size with n_rows and n_cols, by default the memory is uninitialised; memory can be initialised by specifying the fill_type, which is one of: fill::zeros, fill::ones, fill::eye, fill::randu, fill::randn, fill::none_